# Python file status when open() is not assigned to any variable

Tags: python

In Python it is often advised to either use a `with` statement or close an opened file when we are done with it to clean up gracefully. I understand that when using `with` the `__enter__()` and `__exit__()` methods are called. However, what if I don't create a variable from the data stream? Something like this:

```
import json


def read_json(file):
    return json.load(open(file))
```

Would this close the file automatically? Also, is there a way to test this? Thanks.

Comment: Why not use `with` here?

Comment: It's more of a curiosity than actual implementation. I do use with where possible.

Answer (score 1):

In the specific case of `open()`, even though you didn't assign it to a variable, the file is still open, and needs to be closed to avoid leaking a file descriptor. The file is open from the moment that `open()` returns, not when you call `__enter__()`. (`__enter__()` is actually a no-op on the built in file type, though that is not true of all context managers.)

You can see this by tracing the syscalls made by Python:

```
$ strace python3 -c "open('test')"
[...]
openat(AT_FDCWD, "test", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
```

Even though there was no assignment to a variable, or use of a context manager, the `openat()` syscall was still called.

In the same trace, we can see that the `close()` syscall is also invoked afterward:

```
close(3)                                = 0
```

This happens because the file descriptor has no references to it, which invokes the garbage collector, which also closes the file handle if the file handle wasn't explicitly closed.

It's generally considered bad practice to rely on this implementation detail of CPython, however. I suggest that you explictly open and close your files.

Something like this is more clear, does not leak file descriptors, and does not rely on implementation details:

```
def read_json(file):
    with open(file) as f:
        return json.load(f)
```

Comment: I think this explanation is confusing since you are talking about a "variable" going out of scope, but there is no variable holding the file object, and the file gets closed before the `read_json` function ends, so there's no scope change involved with closing the file. I think you mean that the last reference to the file gets released after the `json.load` call returns, which causes the file to be closed right away (in CPython, other interpreters might to garbage collection differently).

Answer (score 1):

Will it close automatically?

Yes.
Upon exiting scope the ref count decrements and the file descriptor closes.
(But don't try to get away with this in Jython!)

---

How to verify?

Consult `os.listdir('/proc/self/fd/')`